# How to form a V-Shape field of view from any given point (i.e. latitude longitude)

Tags: qgis, elevation, latitude-longitude, polygon-creation, azimuth

I want to visualize the V-Shape polygon which can be referred to field of view as well. So, far i have been able to find the latitude and longitude of a certain point when i give an input of latitude and longitude with some specific distance. So, what i have to do next in order to form a full field of view like shape ? I have been studying as well that i have to calculate some angles like azimuth and elevation e.t.c. I got stuck into this and i'm seeing no way out.

Answer (score 2):

I think the easiest way to do this is the **Wedge buffer** QGIS plugin

Note that it's a processing plugin, and it won't appear in the list until you activate the provider. (I found doing that made QGIS 2.16.3 'hang', but shutting it down and restarting QGIS worked for me)

[image]

You'll need a point layer, and add attributes for

- azimuth (direction/bearing of observer)
- angle (your FOV)
- outer radius

optionally, you can also provide an inner radius. The azimuth starts at 0 for North and goes clockwise.

Here's a quick example (azimuth 233, fov 45 degrees) :-

[image]

You could use this in conjunction with Micha's answer to do a partial viewshed, for example showing only the terrain visible through a given camera with a given lens focal length/zoom :)

Answer (score 1):

Field of view, or Viewshed can be constructed with the "Viewshed Analysis" plugin. Not sure what you mean by "V-shape polygon". A Viewshed can be any shape, even a full circle if you're on a mountain top...